# Using Artifactory access token with docker login

Tags: docker, artifactory

I want to run something like:

```
$ TOKEN=$(curl -u <my-name:my-password> -X POST <my-jfrog-artifactory-url>/api/security/token -d "username=my-name" -d"scope=member-of-groups:<???>")
$ docker login <my-jfrog-registry>
Username=my-name
Password=$TOKEN
```

When generating a token with full admin privileges (using curl above, or via UI), this works. I wanted to know what are the minimal permissions I need to give to a user for him to use this token for login, but couldn't find any documentation on this.

What should I pass in `scope=member-of-groups:<???>` above? Create a group with what permissions?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you want the end-user to have the ability to pull images but not push, you will need to assign him to a group that has READ access to the Docker repository(ies). If the Docker repository is a remote repository, you will also need the group to have DEPLOY/CACHE permission if you want them to be able to pull images not already locally cached.

If you want the user to be able to push images to local Docker repositories, the group will need DEPLOY/CACHE permission for that group. If you want to be able to remove/overwrite images, you will need the DELETE permission.

You can check out the full list of permissions and what they do on the [Permissions page in the wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions).

In any case, the idea is that you will assign this token the same permissions that a particular group(s) has to a set of resources.